# Telegram Bot sending a message without needing a ,message to trigger it

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I am trying to let a Telegram bot send a message to a group without the need of a message by a user to trigger it. To be more specific i am trying to set up a birthday reminder where the bot querys a database, compares entries to the current date and broadcaststs a "Happy birthday" message in the group. As said i would like to do it via a cronjob that opens up the PHP script everyday and lets the bot broadcast it.

My problem is I checked all of Telegrams documentations and demo codes (https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples) but all of it are based on a User triggering the bot by sending a message.

My question is, if anyone was already able to implement a similar functionality and could aid me in extending my code? What might be worth mentioning is that the Bot is already integrated into the Group Chat and i have the chat id that would be needed for the bot to target the chat.
My code is as follows (i have to admit i copied it over from the demo examples):

```
<?php

define('BOT_TOKEN', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/');

function apiRequestWebhook($method, $parameters) {
  if (!is_string($method)) {
    error_log("Method name must be a string\n");
    return false;
  }

  if (!$parameters) {
    $parameters = array();
  } else if (!is_array($parameters)) {
    error_log("Parameters must be an array\n");
    return false;
  }

  $parameters["method"] = $method;

  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($parameters);
  return true;
}

function exec_curl_request($handle) {
  $response = curl_exec($handle);

  if ($response === false) {
    $errno = curl_errno($handle);
    $error = curl_error($handle);
    error_log("Curl returned error $errno: $error\n");
    curl_close($handle);
    return false;
  }

  $http_code = intval(curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
  curl_close($handle);

  if ($http_code >= 500) {
    // do not wat to DDOS server if something goes wrong
    sleep(10);
    return false;
  } else if ($http_code != 200) {
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    error_log("Request has failed with error {$response['error_code']}: {$response['description']}\n");
    if ($http_code == 401) {
      throw new Exception('Invalid access token provided');
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    if (isset($response['description'])) {
      error_log("Request was successfull: {$response['description']}\n");
    }
    $response = $response['result'];
  }

  return $response;
}

function apiRequest($method, $parameters) {
  if (!is_string($method)) {
    error_log("Method name must be a string\n");
    return false;
  }

  if (!$parameters) {
    $parameters = array();
  } else if (!is_array($parameters)) {
    error_log("Parameters must be an array\n");
    return false;
  }

  foreach ($parameters as $key => &$val) {
    // encoding to JSON array parameters, for example reply_markup
    if (!is_numeric($val) && !is_string($val)) {
      $val = json_encode($val);
    }
  }
  $url = API_URL.$method.'?'.http_build_query($parameters);

  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

  return exec_curl_request($handle);
}

function apiRequestJson($method, $parameters) {
  if (!is_string($method)) {
    error_log("Method name must be a string\n");
    return false;
  }

  if (!$parameters) {
    $parameters = array();
  } else if (!is_array($parameters)) {
    error_log("Parameters must be an array\n");
    return false;
  }

  $parameters["method"] = $method;

  $handle = curl_init(API_URL);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($parameters));
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));

  return exec_curl_request($handle);
}

function processMessage($message) {
  // process incoming message
  $message_id = $message['message_id'];
  $chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
  if (isset($message['text'])) {
  apiRequest("sendChatAction", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "action" => "typing"));
    // incoming text message
    $text = $message['text'];

    //Command for intializing the backend code for the birthday check (just to check its functionality but would prefer the code to run without a command)
    if (strpos($text, "/geburtstagscheck") === 0) {
      include 'skripte/start.php';
        } 
}}





define('WEBHOOK_URL', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
  // if run from console, set or delete webhook
  apiRequest('setWebhook', array('url' => isset($argv[1]) && $argv[1] == 'delete' ? '' : WEBHOOK_URL));
  exit;
}


$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);

if (!$update) {
  // receive wrong update, must not happen
  exit;
}

if (isset($update["message"])) {
  processMessage($update["message"]);
} ?>
```

Comment: 'i would like to do it via a cronjob' you seem to understand what you need to do, so what is the question? You would just need a file that cron would execute every so often that would read your database and send messages as appropriate.

Comment: No my question is not about doing the cronjob but about the script that is triggered by the cronjob. You see currently it works that way that a user needs to send a message and then the bot replies. But i want the bot to send a message without needing a user to send a message first.

Comment: You would just do a sendMessage with the Chat ID, nothing needs to trigger that.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. I tried doing that but it wont work.  A part of the code prevents it. I think its in the "processMessage" function but i tried removing parts of it and it did not work either.